# How can I clear/empty a div using sencha 4.1.1?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a div with error messages that I want to be emptied before each insertion of another error div, I was wondering if sencha has a function similar to `jQuery's empty()`?

I looked on the docs and searched google and found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For DOM manipulation you can use [`Ext.dom.Element`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element). In your case, the [`update`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-update) function should do the trick:

```
Ext.get('my-div').update();
```

That will update the div's innerHTML to "empty", since the parameter "html" is omitted.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late response, it worked at least :)

Answer (score 1):

update as said by matt is the correct option, but I personally like

```
Ext.get('my-div').destroy();
```

which is overkill